# HTML CSS Responsive cards

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 3 cards in my page, which are laid out in a grid.

The other 2 items are the same, just with different icons and text.

Cards are supposed to have the following properties:

> 1. Be Square shaped
> 2. Have the icon top middle
> 3. Have the cardHeadline centered below the icon
> 4. Have the cardText centered below that
> 5. Be responsive

After much fiddling, I achieved points 1 through 4 with the CSS below.

```css
 .cardsWrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;

    margin-top: 1em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}

.cardWhite {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: rgba(3, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.15rem 0.5rem, rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.075rem 0.175rem;

    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 500ms;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;

}

.cardContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.icon {
    height: 8vw;
    color: black;
}

.cardHeadline {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-size: 1.7vw;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.cardText {
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
```

```html
<section class="cardsWrapper container">
  <div class="cardWhite">
    <div class="cardContent container">
        <img class="icon" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2596/PNG/512/check_one_icon_155665.png"/>
        <a class="cardHeadline">Seamless<br/>working</a>
        <a class="cardText">Thanks to cloud computing</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="cardWhite">
    <div class="cardContent container">
        <img class="icon" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2596/PNG/512/check_one_icon_155665.png"/>
        <a class="cardHeadline">Seamless<br/>working</a>
        <a class="cardText">Thanks to cloud computing</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="cardWhite">
    <div class="cardContent container">
        <img class="icon" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2596/PNG/512/check_one_icon_155665.png"/>
        <a class="cardHeadline">Seamless<br/>working</a>
        <a class="cardText">Thanks to cloud computing</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edit: Using vw as shown in the code above introduced the problem, that the cards, laid out in an auto-fill grid, would for some screen sizes get bigger due to layout. The vw however would linearly decrease, destroying the ratio between card content size and card size.
I played around with % as a unit, but the icon for instance does not seem to resize using that approach.

When I resize, text and icons do not resize accordingly and I have no idea how to implement said wanted behavior. How do I build my cards in a way for them to be completely responsive?

Comment: I tried to fix your example using a sandbox. Let me know if I got it right.

Comment: What do you expect on mobile?

Comment: You are missing a media query like @media (max-width: 50em) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
} (example only).

Comment: @Christian Yeah pretty much, thanks. Only thing that is different from my code is that the items in the cards should be centered horizontally. On mobile the cards should just scale down. I have them in a grid that automatically adds / removes rows to cope with resizing. Mobile should just have smaller cards which are then below one another

Comment: It's still your code :) I have just copied it, added sample images, and duplicated the divs.

Comment: @Christian so the solution would be to just use a media query to set different text sizing? Basically different steps then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be responsive when you change the width of the screen, you need to use VW instead of px and VH.

VH means viewport height, so if you set with VW:

```
.cardText{ 
   font-size: 3vw;
}
```

When you use VH it means that it will be responsive only when you change the height of the screen.

And for icon you need to set:

```
.icon {
   height: 10vw;
}
```

Using PX isn't responsive at all. It is static.

Just change all units to VW.

Also, consider using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) at some point.

Comment: Since the cards are placed in a grid that has auto-fill, they will eventually stack up when the width of the window gets too small. Using vw works fine up to this point, because when they stack up, of course they will take up a big percentage of the screen, however the vw will be small, thus leading to big cards with much too small content. This also happens in some in-between stages, making media queries kind of unfitting for the job. Any ideas?

Comment: It will be great if you share the code to check it and I will give you the full answer. But you will always need to combine VW and media queries since it never will be ideal for all responsive device.

Comment: I updated the code and also added the gist of my comment to the question

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't achieve this for the text only with CSS. It can be possible using javascript and measuring the width of the card. But for image/icon, it is possible. You just need to change the height to width and set the number in %. It will work exactly as you want.